# Reassign to Mat in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have the following function which extracts a sub-image from an OpenCV `cv::Mat`

```
void Process(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    // Extract img(a:b,c:d) each time         
    subImg = img(cv::Range(a, b), cv::Range(c,d));
}
```

I call `Process()` in a loop. On each invocation, the values of `a,b,c,d` keep changing. If `subImg` has been declared as `cv::Mat subImg;`, can I do the above ? i.e. Can OpenCV dynamically resize `subImg` or do I have to go for a pointer-based approach where I declare:

```
cv::Mat* subImg; // Initialized to NULL in constructor
```

and modify the function as follows:

```
void Process(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    // Extract img(a:b,c:d) each time         
    if(subImg) delete subImg;        
    subImg = img(cv::Range(a, b), cv::Range(c,d)).clone();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `cv::Mat subImg;`. `cv::Mat` uses reference counting, and sub-matrix knows that it belongs to bigger matrix, so memory will be deallocated properly.